# Como bloquear a barra de rolagem de uma div específica?

Tags: div, rolamento

Estou criando um novo site, e nele tem uma DIV que ultrapassa o Width do corpo, oque acaba ativando a barra de rolagem do eixo-X. Eu queria saber como fazer para que independentemente do tamanho dessa DIV em especial, que ela não ative as barras de rolagem, mas qualquer outra DIV que ultrapasse o corpo ative as barras normalmente.

Comment: senão me engano é overflow:none; no css

Comment: Sim, existe o Overflow: hidden, quando aplicado no Body faz desaparecer as barras do rolagem nos Eixos X e Y. Mas no meu caso, existe apenas uma unica DIV que está ultrapassando os limites, eu quero que ela, independentemente de seu tamanho, não ative o scroll, mas caso eu crie uma outra que tenha o mesmo tamanho ela ative o scroll normalmente.

Comment: @WallaceMonteiro, você não pode colocar essa div em outra e nessa colocar um `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Poxa era isso então haha. Deu certo aqui.
Me deparei com um outro problema, mas isso já é assunto pra pra outro tópico acredito eu. Muito obrigado Samir!